# Minimum number of numbers to sum to exactly n

Tags: code-golf, number, combinatorics, integer-partitions

First question here, don't yell at me if this is a duplicate or a bad challenge.

## Introduction

I thought of this challenge myself, and it seems to be a good basic puzzle for beginner code-golfers. It also might help me decide which code-golfing language to learn.

## Challenge

Given an array of integers that are less than or equal to `n`, output or return the minimum number of numbers from the array that sum up to exactly `n`.

You can choose to write a function or a full program.

#### Input

You can safely assume `0 <= n < 2^31`.

Take an array or list of any kind (`vector` for C++ or Java's `LinkedList` are allowed), along with `n` and an optional parameter `length`, which specifies the length of the array.

You can also take the input as a space-separated string, separated from `n` by either a comma or a space:

```
1 5 7 3 7 3 6 3 2 6 3,10

1 5 7 3 7 3 6 3 2 6 3 10
```

if it is easier.

#### Output

Output, or return the minimum number of numbers from the array that sum up to exactly `n`. Using the above example:

```
1 5 7 3 7 3 6 3 2 6 3,10
```

Your program should print:

```
2
```

because the minimum number of numbers that sum up to `10` is `2` (`7` and `3`).

In the case that there is no solution, print or return either a negative, `0`, "No solution" (though that would not be smart), `∞` (as suggested), or any other falsy value, with the exception of an empty string.

## Example Input and Output

#### Input:

```
1 5 7 3 7 3 6 3 2 6 3,10
143 1623 1646 16336 1624 983 122,18102
5 6 9,12
```

#### Output:

```
2
3
-1
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

The top answer will be accepted on Christmas.

Comment: I've edited your spec, because we usually allow the same I/O methods for functions and programs; see the consensus [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2455/39328). Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: May we output `false` for cases with no solutions?

Comment: @ETHproductions Sure, will add that.

Comment: Do you consider empty output falsey, since the empty string is falsey in Pyth?

Comment: @ThomasKwa I don't like empty string outputs, but you can include that as "if x was allowed..." in your answer...

Comment: Would ∞ be falsey?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 No, but it makes sense. Will add to challenge description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Pyth, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
lhafqsTQyEY
```

This takes `n` as the first line of input and the list on the second line.

```
lhafqsTQyEY     (Implicit: Q = 1st line of input; E = 2nd line)
         E      The list
        yE      Powerset (sorted by increasing length; empty set first)
   f            Filter by lambda T:
     sT         sum(T)
    q                  ==
       Q                  Q
   fqSTQyE      Sublists that sum to Q, sorted by increasing length
  a       Y     append an empty array (in case none match)
lh              take the length of the first element (0 for empty array)
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lhafqsTQyEY&input=10%0A%5B1%2C5%2C7%2C3%2C7%2C3%2C6%2C3%2C2%2C6%2C3%5D&debug=1).

Comment: Your code and your explanation don't match.

Comment: @isaacg Now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>30</s> <s>21</s> 18 bytes

Turns out there was a much more efficient method. ;)

```
Uà f_x ¥V} ml n- g
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VeAgZl94IKVWfSBtbCBuQFgtWX0gZw==&input=WzEgNSA3IDMgNyAzIDYgMyAyIDYgM10gMTA=) (Note: `n-` has been changed to `n@X-Y}` for compatibility reasons)

This takes input as a space- or comma-separated array, followed by a number. Outputs `undefined` for test cases without solutions.

```
Uà f_  x ¥ V} ®   l} n- g
UàfmZ{Zx ==V} mZ{Zl} n- g

            // Implicit: U = input array, V = input integer
Uà fZ{   }  // Generate all possible combinations of U, then filter to only items Z where
Zx ==V      //   the sum of Z is equal to V.
mZ{Zl}      // Map each remaining combination to its length.
n-          // Sort by subtraction; smaller items end up in the front.
g           // Take the first item.
            // Implicit: output last expression
```

I can't believe I didn't think of this version when I originally wrote this...

Several optimizations have been made since then which come in handy here:

- A `U` at the beginning of the program can usually be left out.
- `Ã` is a shortcut for `}` .
- `n` now sorts numbers properly by default.

Each of these takes off a byte, for a total of 15:

```
à f_x ¥VÃml n g
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=4CBmX3ggpVbDbWwgbiBn&input=WzEgNSA3IDMgNyAzIDYgMyAyIDYgM10gMTA=)

Comment: That's 25 bytes, not 21.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Japt supports the [IEC_8859-1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), under which each of these characters is 1 byte. You can save this program as a IEC_8859-1-encoded text file, then upload it to the [online interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt).

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks for informing me

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, <s>73</s> 65 bytes

```
Min[Length/@Select[IntegerPartitions[#2,#2,#],Sort@#==Union@#&]]&
```

Pure function, returns `∞` if there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 128 bytes

This isn't as golfed as I'd like it to be, but I'll work on it later.

```
from itertools import*
def s(a,n):
 for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in permutations(a,i+1):
   if sum(j)==n:return i+1
 return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 45 bytes

```
Min@Cases[Subsets@#,i_/;Tr@i==12:>Length@#2]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 34 bytes

```
0q~_,2,m*\f.*{:+1$=},\;0f-{,}$0=,+
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0q~_%2C2%2Cm*%5Cf.*%7B%3A%2B1%24%3D%7D%2C%5C%3B0f-%7B%2C%7D%240%3D%2C%2B&input=18102%20%5B143%201623%201646%2016336%201624%20983%20122%5D). The input format is the sum followed by the list of values, e.g.:

```
18102 [143 1623 1646 16336 1624 983 122]
```

Note that this will raise an exception if no solution is found. The exception goes to stderr when CJam is run from the command line, and the correct result (`0`) is still printed to stdout. So this meets the consensus established at [Should submissions be allowed to exit with an error?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error)

The code may look longer than you would expect. The main reason is that CJam has no built-in for generating combinations. Or at least that's my excuse, and I'm sticking to it.

Explanation:

```
0       Push 0 result for exception case.
q~      Get and interpret input.
_,      Copy and get length of input value list.
2,      Push [0 1].
m*      Cartesian power. This generates all possible lists of 0/1 values with the
        same length as the input value list.
\       Swap input value list to top.
f.*     Apply element-wise product of input value list with all 0/1 lists.
        We now have all combinations of values, with 0 in place of unused values.
{       Start filter block.
  :+      Sum values.
  1$      Copy target sum to top.
  =       Compare.
},      Filter.
\;      Swap target sum to top and discard.
0f-     Remove 0 values. We now have all solution lists.
{,}$    Sort by length.
0=      Get first solution, which after sorting is the shortest.
        This will raise an exception if the list of solutions is empty, bailing
        out with the initial 0 on the stack.
,       Get length of solution.
+       Add the 0 we initially pushed for the exception case.
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 84 bytes

```js
f=(a,n,m=1e999,x)=>n&&a.map((v,i)=>(x=[...a],x.splice(i,1),x=f(x,n-v)+1)<m?m=x:0)&&m
```

### Explanation

Takes an `Array` of `Number`s and a `Number` as arguments. Returns a number of `Infinity` if no result. It is a recursive function that subtracts from `n` and removes each element from the array one-by-one until `n == 0`.

```js
f=(a,n,m=1e999,x)=> // m and x are not passed, they are here to declare them in the local
                    //     scope instead of globally, initialise m to Infinity
  n&&               // if n == 0, return 0
  a.map((v,i)=>     // iterate over each number in a
    (x=[...a],      // x = copy of a
    x.splice(i,1),  // remove the added number from the array
    x=f(x,n-v)+1)   // x = result for the numbers in this array
      <m?m=x:0      // set m to minimum result
  )
  &&m               // return m
```

### Test

This test sets `m` to `Infinity` later instead of as a default argument to make it work in Chrome (instead of just Firefox).

```js
var solution = f=(a,n,m,x)=>n&&a.map((v,i)=>(x=[...a],x.splice(i,1),x=f(x,n-v)+1)<m?m=x:0,m=1e999)&&m
```

```html
Array (space-delimited) = <input type="text" id="array" value="143 1623 1646 16336 1624 983 122" /><br />
n = <input type="number" id="N" value="18102" /><br />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(array.value.split` `,N.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
import Data.List
n#l=head$sort[length x|x<-subsequences l,sum x==n]++[0]
```

Returns `0` if there's no solution.

Usage example: `10 # [1,5,7,3,7,3,6,3,2,6,3]` -> `2`.

Find all sub-lists of the input list `l` which have a sum of `n`. Take the length of each such sub-list and sort. Append a `0` and take the first element.

If a singleton list is allowed for output, e.g. `[2]`, we can save 7 bytes:  `n#l=minimum[length x|x<-subsequences l,sum x==n]`. In case of no solution, the empty list `[]` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ṗ'∑₀=;vLg
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%97%27%E2%88%91%E2%82%80%3D%3BvLg&inputs=%5B1%2C5%2C7%2C3%2C7%2C3%2C6%2C3%2C2%2C6%2C3%5D%0A10&header=&footer=)

```
ṗ         # Powerset
 '   ;    # Filtered by
  ∑₀=     # Sublists that sum to input
      vL  # Get length of each
        g # Minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒPS=¥ƇẈṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIBg20NLj7U/3NXxcGfT/8PLlSL//4821DHVMdcxBmMzIDYCkbE6CtGmQIZl7H9DAx0FQyMA)

Outputs `0` if there's no solution

### How it works

```
ŒPS=¥ƇẈṂ - Main link. Takes L on the left and n on the right
ŒP       - Powerset of L
    ¥Ƈ   - Keep those lists for which the following is true:
  S      -   The sum...
   =     -   ...equals n
      Ẉ  - Lengths of those kept
       Ṃ - Minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
def f(l,t):
 s={0:0}
 for i in l:s|={k+i:min(s[k]+1,s.get(k+i,s[k]+1))for k in s}
 return s.get(t,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoIwDIbve4rG0xqnoRsgkvAkxpsgCxMIGzFGfXbsxIOH/vn792va8RHaoTfLcqkbaKRTAUsBvnomZfIW0AwTWLA9uNK/qme3teXN9tKfuvOWlN9f6yA5VGuAGPku8p6XpzrME9svFdSOcLm31tVAfIIvQcXkOAeJez86G@RGbVDAmvMGe8f@FBuLf7/8cDwLGKc4XR/HhSCDA5hv5Vw6qqJEUGqAch0lzVmMiapTOBacaa2ooESLjPmjIv0B)

Note : the `|=` operators was introduced in python 3.9 but TIO doesn't support that version.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 105 bytes

```python
def f(l,t):s={0:0};[s.update({k+i:min(s[k]+1,s.get(k+i,s[k]+1))for k in s})for i in l];return s.get(t,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7RasMwDEXf/RWiTxb1QmSnWZvSLwl5GNRZTbzUxA6jlH57KieDPehydXwlOTzS7T6aZbnaHnrpVcImXp5lU77ObSzmcP1KVj6HvWt@3ChjO3R7UrH4tkkyVBtA7O8TDOBGiK/Vu@x9d55smiem60BSH4TL7815C9QI4Gtw4WCYk8QiBu@S3KkdCtg4T7D37NvcOIT/1X9x7ASEKb9un8eF4ACfYNaquXRWRaWgygDVOktVsxiTVVdwOjLTWtGRSi0OnD8p0m8)

### Ungolfed version:

```python
def f(l,t):
  s={0:0}              # initialize the reached numbers
  for i in l:          # iterate through the list
    new_s = {}           # create a dict for the newly reached numbers
    for k in s:          # iterate through all the reached numbers
      new_s[k+i] = min(s[k]+1,s.get(k+i,s[k]+1)) # set the new number to the minimal number of steps
    s.update(new_s)      # update out dict with the new values
  return s.get(t,-1)   # returns the number of steps or -1 if the number is unreachable
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJhb4IwEP3Or7hsX2hEQ0GdmvhLjFmqFLlYgdBjxhl/O7tSNZJsI@mlfXfv3ruW@kJFVaZdl@kc8tBEJFYBgF1f41V8g8H3DlgioTL4rYEKDY1W@0JnULannW4s8/KqAeQyMKsBj3SjyJGaqj0UPdmgpcClS33@tLCG622gtefuTFGQ4Z76xo7Fxebyi7CXPjpp@6@0MuYP708vm@MIt2zohGXIh@1IRnZy0BQyHnlACG5tNT083dsAVT3CTDwp80CrHCzp2ovYSVtn7CjstcTDpwehaskPfEYqnt2/lGm1ozea2oZH7O1QNJaiJ3vY@vqhJvC1jCVg/ppEC23Z34DaGd2dCzQaJD88vz8PjmXdUigmtjZI4Vv0JgLwOIvy3vB@4w4oXl78Xi62AdSNy/rfSXQSZvABab/mvBIXIxkHcpqCnCcuTOcc0tTFZArLBWNJEsmFjJNgxvXLSCY/)

### Note:

there is probably some potential